# Firefox IFrame issue ( From 3.6 version to 8)

Tags: firefox, iframe

Below is the code . This is working fine on IE8 and Chrome , But on Firefox upto version 8 I am having a problem .

Issue :- On Firefox it just displays some advertisements instead of the actual content .

Could some one help me on this ? Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

        <style type="text/css">
            <!--
            #container{
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            #container iframe {
                width:1000px;
                height:930x;
                margin-left:-680px;
                margin-top:-230px;
                border:0;
             }
            -->
        </style>

    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="container">
            <iframe src="http://www.tsn.ca/" scrolling="no" height="930"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same charset used by iframe, which is `utf-8`

Comment: Thanks and tried , but that didn't help either . Am I doing some thing wrong ?